# Simple For Each through OLEObjects

Tags: excel, vba

I just have a simple loop:

```
    Dim o As OLEObject
    For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, o.Name, "abc") Then
            MsgBox o.Visible = False
        End If
    Next o
```

This should display names of my ActiveX buttons, but it doesn't. When I debug the program, For Each loop doesn't start ever once.

I used `Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets(1).OLEObjects.Visible = False` and it works fine for my all buttons. Does anyone know why my loop doesn't works or how to set Visible property of buttons that name contains "abc"?

I tried:

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B6:C20")) Is Nothing Or Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H20")) Is Nothing Then
            'Me.OLEObjects.Visible = False <-- This works fine
            Dim o As OLEObject
            For Each o In Me.OLEObjects
                MsgBox o.Visible = False
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code in a worksheet's private code sheet or are you trying to run it through every button in the workbook? If the former then try For Each o In me.OLEObjects.

Comment: It looks like your difference is that your single-line attempt was very specific in referencing the workbook and a single worksheet. Your loop code is very non-specific and references (probably) the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: It's in private code sheet, in Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange, me.OLEObject doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
For Each o In OLEObjects
```

with

```
For Each o In Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets(1).OLEObjects
```

You should probably put something other than what I put before the OLEObjects, but you'll need a sheet reference of some kind.

Comment: Just forgot that, i added .ActiveSheet but it still doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent parentage to an OLEObject (singular) and the OLEObjects (plural) collection belongs to a worksheet, not a workbook (beyond .parent.parent) and certainly not the Application object.

If you're trying to access the buttons on a worksheet from that worksheet's private code sheet then,

```
private sub meh()

    Dim o As OLEObject
    For Each o In ME.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, o.Name, "abc") Then
            MsgBox o.Visible = False
        End If
    Next o

end sub
```

If you're trying to access the OLEObjects in another worksheet or from a public module code sheet then resort to a fully qualified parent as you've done previously.

```
public sub meh2()
    with Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets(1)
            Dim o As OLEObject
            For Each o In .OLEObjects    '<~~ note .OLEObjects inside the With ... End With
                If InStr(1, o.Name, "abc") Then
                    MsgBox o.Visible = False
                End If
            Next o
    end with
end sub
```